# How to SUM results from two or more identical mysql tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I've got a couple of identical tables. They look like this:

```
Table 1 
--------------------
Username      Points 
User 1            10 
User 2            15 
User 2            1 
User 1            3 

Table 2
---------------------
Username       Points 
User 1             10 
User 2             15 
User 2             5 
User 1             15
```

I'm using  `SELECT username, SUM( points ) AS total_points` to calculate the points for particular user. And it workds perfect. But i want to SUM the results from two or more tables. Is that possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  If an answer to your question proved useful, please accept it by clicking on the green checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UNION ALL` if you don't want to discard duplicates between the tables.

```
select username, sum(points) as total_points
from (
  select username, points
  from table_1
  union all
  select username, points
  from table_2
) t
```

If you use `UNION` instead, then rows with the same username and points will only be counted (summed) once

But it sounds like you actually should put that into a single table. You might want to read up on database normalization.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfect! :)))